# duty of contourplot for lists and import data containing $\pi$

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, export, import

We have two lists with plot: ( Because they are not very short we uploaded `list1` and `list2`,[here](https://ufile.io/y3rf7) and [here](https://ufile.io/392ms))

[image]

In some regions the values related to the `z` axis of `list2` gets exceeding from the values related to the `z` axis of `list1`. We specified these regions with red color.

**Main Question**: Because we have *data* and not *functions*, we could not use `ContourPlot` to show these areas. How can we present these zones in a `2` dimensional plane.

**Second Question:** We exploited

`Export["list1.txt", list1, "Table"];`

and

`read = Import["list1.txt", "Table"];`

to save and read data. But in importing, we think `Pi` will not be imported in a suitable format. How can we import data which contain `Pi` as $\pi$?

Comment: `read = ToExpression[Import["list1.txt", "Table"]];` works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lst1 = Import["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/list1.txt", "Table"] // 
   ToExpression;

lst2 = Import["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/list2.txt", "Table"] // 
   ToExpression;
```

The lists have the same length and the data lies on the same grid.

```
{Length[lst1] == Length[lst2], (Most /@ lst1) == (Most /@ lst2)}

(* {True, True} *)
```

The absolute differences of the `z` values are

```
lst3 = Append @@@ 
   Transpose[{Most /@ lst1, Abs[(Last /@ lst1) - (Last /@ lst2)]}];
```

Using [`ListContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListContourPlot.html) for the absolute differences

```
ListContourPlot[lst3,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Looking only at `lst2 > lst1`

```
lst4 = Append @@@ 
   Transpose[{Most /@ lst1, 
     Max[#, 0] & /@ ((Last /@ lst2) - (Last /@ lst1))}];

ListContourPlot[lst4, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White, Red}, #] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, If we ignore `Abs`, I think the considered zones are more clear. It would be very desired if all differences (of two lists) get zero except when `list2>list1`, in this case, the color of all `ListContourPlot` zones will be the same except while `list2>list1`

Comment: `list3 = Table[{i, j, 0}, {i, 0, 4 \[Pi], \[Pi]/16}, {j, collection}]`;             
  `list3new = Flatten[list3, 1]`;`Do[
 
 If[list1[[i]][[3]] - list2[[i]][[3]] < 0, 
  list3new[[i]][[3]] = 
   list2[[i]][[3]] - list1[[i]][[3]]]
 
 
 , {i, 1, Length@list2}]`

Comment: the above code approximately does the goal but in an unprofessional way. Your guidance is more professional than mine. Thanks a bunch!!